# Is there a way to turn my flex 50/50 Split View CSS to 70/30?

Tags: html, css

```css
html {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  }
  
  *, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .split-view {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: #111;
  }
  
  .box {
    position: relative;
    flex-basis: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.6s all cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.6, 0.7, 1);
    background-position: center;
  }
  
  .box:hover {
    flex-basis: calc(100% / 13 * 9);
  }
  
  .box__overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.8s all ease-out;
    transition: 0.8s all cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  
  .box-1 {
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
  }
  
  .box-1 .box__overlay {
    background-color: rgba(96, 155, 116, 0.2);
  }
  
  .box-1:hover .box__overlay {
    background-color: rgba(96, 155, 116, 0.1);
  }
  
  .box-1 .box__title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0.5em 0.8em;
    color: white;
    font-size: calc(30px + 20 * ((100vw - 320px) / 680));
    word-spacing: 100vw;
  }
  
  .box-2 {
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
  }
  
  .box-2 .box__overlay {
    background-color: rgba(96, 155, 116, 0.8);
  }
  
  .box-2:hover .box__overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 157, 157, 0.5);
  }
  
  .box-2 .box__title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0.5em 0.8em;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: calc(30px + 15 * ((100vw - 320px) / 680));
    word-spacing: 100vw;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Oco, online coworking</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kanit:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/home.css') }}" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<section class="split-view">
  <div class="box box-1">
    <a href="{{ url_for('study_hub')}}" class="box__overlay">
      <h1 class="box__title">Study Hub</h1>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="box box-2">
    <div class="box__overlay">
      <h1 class="box__title">About</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

</body>

</html>
```

**complete beginner, stuck at this, 'elp**

I'm trying to access the individual boxes' css so I can change the ratio to a 70/30 screen layout, rather than the current 50/50, but no matter what I change it either completely scuffs my transitions, or the whole thing breaks.
Any of my trial and error details will likely not be of any help either, sooo sorry to just hand this to you. <3

Comment: Could you give each box it's own `flex-basis`? For example: `.box-1 { flex-basis: 70%; } .box-2 { flex-basis: 30% }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? Just give the boxes individual `flex-basis` values. Right now they both share the same value of `50%`. Even if you change that to something like `70%`, they both share the same value and they both can't take `70%` so it effectively remains at `50%`.

```css
html {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  }
  
  *, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .split-view {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: #111;
  }
  
  .box {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.6s all cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.6, 0.7, 1);
    background-position: center;
  }
  
  .box:hover {
    flex-basis: calc(100% / 13 * 9);
  }
  
  .box__overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.8s all ease-out;
    transition: 0.8s all cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  
  .box-1 {
    flex-basis: 30%;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
  }
  
  .box-1 .box__overlay {
    background-color: rgba(96, 155, 116, 0.2);
  }
  
  .box-1:hover .box__overlay {
    background-color: rgba(96, 155, 116, 0.1);
  }
  
  .box-1 .box__title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0.5em 0.8em;
    color: white;
    font-size: calc(30px + 20 * ((100vw - 320px) / 680));
    word-spacing: 100vw;
  }
  
  .box-2 {
    flex-basis: 70%;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
  }
  
  .box-2 .box__overlay {
    background-color: rgba(96, 155, 116, 0.8);
  }
  
  .box-2:hover .box__overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 157, 157, 0.5);
  }
  
  .box-2 .box__title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0.5em 0.8em;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: calc(30px + 15 * ((100vw - 320px) / 680));
    word-spacing: 100vw;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Oco, online coworking</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kanit:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/home.css') }}" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<section class="split-view">
  <div class="box box-1">
    <a href="{{ url_for('study_hub')}}" class="box__overlay">
      <h1 class="box__title">Study Hub</h1>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="box box-2">
    <div class="box__overlay">
      <h1 class="box__title">About</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh, nice! flex-basis was indeed helpful!

Time to craft a different transition for it, now that there's no space for one side to expand anymore hehe, from one task to another, loving it.
Thanks, have a great day.

Comment: @StonkZoomer Don't forget to accept and upvote this user's answer if it was helpful and solved your problem.

Comment: @War10ck Sadly can't upvote yet! Thanks for making me aware of the "accepting" an answer.